# SwiftUI how to navigate to nested navigation link pages in NavigationStack?

Tags: swiftui

I have a really simple `NavigationStack` based navigation flow where you  are supposed to start at the home page, go deeper into the 'kitchen' and then into the 'lounge'.

I do have the navigation working for the most par.  After I have tapped "Enter Home" on the home page, I can enter the kitchen but **then I can't go any deeper.** It keeps navigating to the kitchen over and over again upon each tap.

I think this is because of this XCode warning.

`A navigationDestination for “Swift.String” was declared earlier on the stack. Only the destination declared closest to the root view of the stack will be used`.

However, I don't know what change to make to my routing to do to make this warning go away and so that I can enter home > kitchen > lounge and get back one step at a time and also be able to 'pop to the root' from lounge straight back to the home page.

```
import SwiftUI


struct HomePage: View {
    
    @State private var path = NavigationPath()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $path) {
            Text("My home")
            
            
            NavigationLink("Enter home", value: "root")
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { navItem in
                    KitchenPage(path: $path)
                    
                }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}


struct KitchenPage: View {
    
    @Binding  var path : NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("This is the kitchen  ")
            NavigationLink("Go Deeper", value: "lounge")
                .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { navItem in
                    LoungePage(path: $path)
                }
            
            Button("Back by one") {
                path.removeLast()
            }
            
            Button("Back to root") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}



struct LoungePage: View {
    
    @Binding  var path : NavigationPath
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            
            Text("This is the lounge ")
            NavigationLink("Go Deeper", value: "another lounge")
            
            Button("Back by one") {
                path.removeLast()
            }
            
            Button("Back to root") {
                path = NavigationPath()
            }
            
        }
        
    }
}





#Preview {
    HomePage()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error message says, you should not "nest" `.navigationDestination(for: String.self)`. You should not declare the same type of navigation destination (in this case, `String`), more than once in a navigation path.

You can check for them all in `HomePage`:

```
.navigationDestination(for: KitchenDestinations.self) { navItem in
    switch navItem {
        case "root":
            KitchenPage(path: $path)
        case "lounge", "another lounge":
            LoungePage(path: $path)
        default:
            EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to handle all of them in `HomePage`, you can make up different types for different navigation destinations. After all, you are already using the `NavigationPath` type, designed for heterogenous destination types. For example, you can use `enum`s.

```
enum HomeDestinations {
    case kitchen
}

enum KitchenDestinations {
    case lounge
    // you can add associated values to these cases if you also need to pass some data
    // for example, if lounges need a name
    // case lounge(name: String)
}
```

In `HomePage`, declare the destinations for `HomeDestinations`:

```
NavigationLink("Enter home", value: HomeDestinations.kitchen)
    .navigationDestination(for: HomeDestinations.self) { navItem in
        // you should check navItem here if you have multiple destinations!
        KitchenPage(path: $path)
    }
```

In `KitchenPage`, declare the destinations for `KitchenDestinations`

```
NavigationLink("Go Deeper", value: KitchenDestinations.lounge)
    .navigationDestination(for: KitchenDestinations.self) { navItem in
        LoungePage(path: $path)
    }
```

Since you want "Go Deeper" in the Lounge to go to another lounge for some reason, you can reuse `KitchenDestinations.lounge`:

```
NavigationLink("Go Deeper", value: KitchenDestinations.lounge)
```

Comment: THANK YOU! It has taken me hours and hours of reading tutorials and not getting anywhere. I didn't want to handle all the destinations in home page which all examples seem to do. Using your second example, I finally realised that the .navigationDestination needs to only be used as a modifier once, regardless of how many actual destinations there are. Maybe this is intuitive for an experienced iOS developer but coming from a non-ios world it really isn't.